# Input raíz cuadrada de un número en Python

Tags: python, input, math

Quiero introducir mediante un input una raíz cuadrada, he intentado con:

```
IN: sqrt(5)
```

pero no me deja.

Aquí muestro el código:

```
import math

root = math.sqrt(input("Introduce una raiz cuadrada de un número: "))
print(root)
```

Comment: debes hace un `cast` a `int` ya que input devuelve lo escrito como `string`

Comment: @Bryro. ¿Te refieres a la función `cast()` o al hecho de aplicar `int()`?

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'srqt(2)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sugerencia

```
from math import sqrt
root = eval(input("Introduce una raiz cuadrada de un número: "))
print(root)
```

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'sqrt(5)'

Comment: ¿que dato estas ingresando?

Comment: He intentado con: sqrt(5), √5, √(5), por ejemplificar mis entradas.

Comment: acabo de corregir el codigo, te permitira meter una expresion como sqrt(25)

Comment: Que crack, muchas gracias :)

Comment: `eval()` es peligroso. Prueba a ejecutar ese programa y cuando te pregunte lo de la raiz cuadrada responderle con `exec('import os; print(os.listdir("/"))')` (y porque no quiero ser malo y ponerle un comando que borre algún fichero)

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes la respuesta:

```
from math import sqrt

root = float(input("Introduce una raiz cuadrada de un número: "))
print(sqrt(root))
```

Un saludo ;)